# Faster Data Transfer?

Tags: performance

I'm doing a project which involves a small dataset (4GB). I'm trying to upload it to Paperspace to do some analysis but it's taking an absurd amount of time.

- Using Gradient, it would upload maybe 40MB in 10min then stop uploading. This was done using the "upload" button in the jupyter notebook.
- Using a P400 hourly computer I'm transferring at 800MBPS over SSH (well, through Nautilus), but it's still taking hours to transfer this small dataset.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a faster way?

Comment: I wouldn't call 4GB a small dataset, but anyway I think you should ask Paperspace support.

Answer (score 0):

Most cloud systems support the command line `mv` utility to move files or folders.

Taking a command line approach allows for more control and visibility into tasks.